# EditText get drawable left

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to get `EditText` current left drawable ?

I have some `EditText` where i set the left drawable whit those lines of code :

```
cod.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ok, 0, 0, 0); 
cod.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.notok, 0, 0, 0);
```

And i want at a certain time to check what is the current drawable on my `EditText`.

I search but i did not find a way to get current drawable. If there is no way to do this : is there a way to add a note to my `EditText`? Like setting color, `TextSize`.... a way to set a note (text).

Thanks!

Comment: or... is there a way to btnd to view's ? An EditText with an TextView by same id ?

Comment: try this edittext.setTag(note); , here note can be any type of object.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @balaji : you are the man ! Solved my problem. I can not give you a vote... or any appreciation. Post it like a solution and i will vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `edittext.setTag(note);` , here note can be any type of object. here is a supported [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to use the method "getCompoundDrawables()". This will return a drawable array with drawables for the left, top, right, and bottom borders.

I haven't used this method yet but i believe the left drawable would logically be [0].